# GAE list bucket file return void

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, bucket

I'm trying to have the list of files into a bucket on Google Cloud Storage, unfortunately my script return always a void list, while there are some file into the bucket.

```
bucket_name = 'myBucket'
stats = cloudstorage.listbucket(
    bucket_name + '/myfolder', 
    max_keys = page_size, 
    prefix = ''
)

print(stats)
for stat in stats:
    print(stat)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a soluction

```
client = None
if path_to_json is None:
    client = storage.Client()
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(path_to_json)

bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
file_list = [blob.name for blob in bucket.list_blobs()]
```

Comment: You are creating your client twice if path_to_json is None. The second time it will fail.